# UTF8 parameter in query string GET

Tags: php, string, get

I often see UTF8 parameter in query string. What does it mean? how to work with it and how to handle it?

*example:*

```
http://themeforest.net/item/bridge-creative-multipurpose-wordpress-theme/7315054/comments?utf8=%E2%9C%93&term=custom&from_buyers_and_authors_only=0
```

Comment: What does the form look like?

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your question can be found at [http://programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168751/is-the-use-of-utf8-preferable-to-utf8-true)

> By default, older versions of IE (<=8) will submit form data in Latin-1 encoding if possible. By including a character that can't be expressed in Latin-1, IE is forced to use UTF-8 encoding for its form submissions, which simplifies various backend processes, for example database persistence.
>     If the parameter was instead utf8=true then this wouldn't trigger the UTF-8 encoding in these browsers.